# How to get wordpress to stay local?

Tags: wordpress

I have an existing wordpress that I copied to my localhost (including databases). I changed the `wp-config.php` for localhost, but when I try to go to wordpress/wp-admin, it connects to my live site...

What do I need to change? (btw, using XAMMP)

Comment: What URL did you type on your browser to go to your local wordpress/wp-admin?

Comment: localhost/site/wordpress/wp-admin -It just takes me to the online log in system.

Comment: The local copy of wordpress requires you to log in too.

Comment: Right... but it isn't really local if it connects to the web. It goes to the online site, online database, etc.

Comment: So you mean if you make a change in local, then you go to your live site, you will see the changes?

Comment: No. When I go to wp-admin, it automatically redirects me to the online site. I guess I'll have to do a clean install and restore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these two lines to your wp-config.php, where "`http://localhost/wordpress/`" is the correct location of your site.

```
define('WP_HOME','http://localhost/wordpress/');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://localhost/wordpress/');
```

or check in table wp_options column `option_name = siteurl` check the `option_value`

Please refer here for more information http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Comment: Worked like a charm. Now I just have to figure out how to get the user/pass to work haha. Thank you both.

Answer (score 1):

You must edit the URL's in the Wordpress database. Open up your WP database with PhpMyAdmin or another MySQL browser and then open the `wp_options` table. The first entry is the `siteurl` and you must change this to your localhost url (don't forget to include the localhost port if you have one example: `http://localhost:8888/wordpress`).