# Error with moving Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, caching

I've moved a WP installation from [thedepartment.dk/test](http://thedepartment.dk/test) to [nordes.org/nordes2013](http://nordes.org/nordes2013) .. I copied the files from thedepartment.dk/test domain and deleted the old site on nordes.org/nordes2013 domain.

After that I moved the mysql-database from thedepartment.dk and imported the mysql-database in a new database on the nordes.org/nordes2013 host.

I ran a search/replace in the mysql-database and replaced all the thedepartment.dk/test URL with nordes.org/nordes2013 URL .. After that I configured wp-config.php with all the new settings.

But when I visit the site, it's af is it links to the old nordes.org/nordes2013 but when I refresh the new site works

Any ideas? I've followed the codex and I've moved WP before. Could it be some caching issue?  The problem occurs after a clearing the cache in Firefox/Chrome/Safari

Comment: The problem is not very clear. Are you getting the index page and the links point to the old site? Or are you trying to login to the backend and you get forwarded to the old domain?

Comment: No idea what your problem really is but this page might help: http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Comment: try refer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15800724/how-to-get-wordpress-to-stay-local/15804043#15804043

Answer (score 0):

Check if WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) still point to the old domain.

You find this at:

**Dashboard > General > Settings**

Answer (score 0):

try to put this in your wp-config.php

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

or you can delete your .htaccess (have a back up) and refresh your permalinks to the very basic.